# Selector for Buttons not working after setting backgroundResource of the button in Android

Tags: android, button, background, selector

I have applied the follwoing selector to all my buttons by specifying it in my theme:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_pressed"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_focussed"
    android:state_focused="true" />     
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_normal" />
</selector>
```

This works fine. But I want the background of the button to remain "@drawable/my_btn_pressed" when the button is pressed, as if to highlight that this was the last button pressed. Hence, I added the code in my `onClick()` to set the background resource:

```
infoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            infoButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_btn_pressed);
            otherButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_btn_normal);
        }
    });
```

This also works to highlight the last pressed button with "my_btn_pressed". However after this, my selector properties do not seem to work on the other buttons. Mainly, the state focussed is not distinguishable, at all.

Any idea how I can do both, i.e distinguish focussed, pressed and normal states of the button, as well as highlight the last pressed button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, the solution I found for this one may not be really correct, but I used this workaround, since I had no other go!

When the info button is focussed, i.e in `onFoucsChangeListener()`, use `infoButton.setSelected(true);` and similarly, set all other buttons as unselected. Do not set the background resource!

In selector.xml, add an item

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_focussed" 
    android:state_focused="true" />
```

This should help in setting the selected button as highlighted!